# Retrieve password for Fedora 14

Tags: linux, fedora, forgot-password, password-retrieval

Hello I use a Fedora 14 VM on my Macbook pro. I haven't logged into it for a while and now I have forgot its password, I am trying to see if there is a way I could retrieve my password. I have looked around on google, and all I get is how to change a root password, but I am not looking for that.

I am stuck at the initial login screen, and am trying to see if I can retrieve my password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, all i needed was a little patience. Below link would help us as to how to modify the password.

This one shows how to edit password for root, if someone wants to change the password for a user, then it has to be passwd username.

http://www.labtestproject.com/using_linux/step_by_step_to_reset_change_root_password_on_fedora_10

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you can still have full access to grub, you can add the argument "init=/bin/sh" to the kernel argument, and then boot the system. This will bring you directly to the shell (no password is asked). From there you can modify the /etc/passwd file as ease and get your system back to work.